# Service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' which was not registered

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I received this error: Does anyone know what can possibly be causing this?

```
 Service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' which was not registered.
```

However, I have DB Context setup in Startup CS.

```
 services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(connstring));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Using DbContext with dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection):

> `AddDbContext<TContext>` will make both your `DbContext`
>   type, `TContext`, and the
>   corresponding `DbContextOptions<TContext>` available for injection
>   from the service container.

---

It appears that you're trying to inject the `DbContext` class, which likely looks something like:

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public MyController(DbContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

However, you should be injecting the class that *derives from* `DbContext` since that's what you configured with the `services.AddDbContext<TestContext>`. This would look like:

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly TestContext _context;

    public MyController(TestContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: what's the correct code then? it seems the coworker is injecting testcontext

Comment: *Somewhere* `DbContext` is what's being injected, based purely on the exception. `DbContext` is never going to be in the service collection no matter what - only derivations of it. Search your project for `DbContext` and look for an instance where it's a constructor param.